# Can't get PHP flush to work no matter what I try

Tags: php, ajax, flush

Ok for the life of me I can't figure out why flush() isn't working.  I've googled this issue EVERYWHERE with no success.  At the moment i don't have nginx or fastCGI (which have been mentioned as having special needs).  I have a php.ini override file in place to change these values:

```
output_buffering = Off
implicit_flush = 1
zlib.output_compression = 0
```

I've tried everything under the sun in the actual php but this is what i currently have:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
header('Content-Encoding: none;');
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
header("Connection: close");
echo 'success?';
ob_flush();
flush();

/******** background process starts here ********/

sleep(2);
echo 'dammit';
```

This is just test info really.  The end goal is to submit data via an ajax POST using jquery and send back a success and continue processing the information.  The user is NOT supposed to wait while the rest of the script runs.  I can't even get this to work if i call the file directly!  Both of the echos spit out at the same time no matter how i work it!

Comment: run it in the background, poll a db for the results, i dont think using flush is the correct apporach

Comment: It has always been my understanding that `flush()` is dependent on the user agent, and most user agents will wait for a minimum amount of content before updating. This is why a number of systems that rely on flushing use something like `echo str_pad('', 4096);` to get up to the minimum threshold... however I have no idea if this will work as you expect over AJAX (it is unlikely), as the way those requests are dealt with is different to how an agent renders a page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14574432/why-do-i-need-str-pad-4096-to-make-php-flushing-work

Comment: What `ob_get_level()` says?

Comment: `ob_flush()` sends the current contents of the output buffer.  It looks like you're not using output buffering, so the buffer will be empty and `ob_flush()` won't do anything.  Your output has been sent to the client already.

Comment: `ob_get_level()` is showing 1.  Dagon I would rather have this all happen in one call.  This actually was working and then my host decided to upgrade PHP to 5.3 from 5.2.  The `ob_flush()` isn't working even with `output_buffering` on and `implicit_flush` off.  Im really leaning towards this being something unusual like a php setting or a weird server setting.

Comment: 2 more things.  I tried this with padding and that wasnt the issue.  Also the ob_flush doesnt work yes, but the echo should have went through none the less.  I had it in there just in case really.  ANYTHING that will work I will take lol

Answer (score 3):

Heavens forgive me for this code:

```
protected function detachBrowser()
{
    ob_start();

    // tell PHP to ignore if the browsers closes connection
    @ignore_user_abort(true);
    // check it worked 
    $defer = @ignore_user_abort();
    // according to the docs, in some cases on IIS+CGI
    // ignore_user_abort does not work
    // If so, just abort.
    if (!$defer)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Webserver does not support ignore_user_abort()");
    }

    // remove the buffer, even nested ones
    while (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();

    /* close the frigging connection with the browser, and help IE understand the message */
    ob_start();
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    header('Content-Length: 0');
    header("Content-Encoding: none\r\n");
    header('Connection: close');
    // we need all three, in this precise order
    @flush();
    @ob_end_flush();
    @ob_flush();
}
```

**Edit:** I derived this code from [DokuWiki](https://www.dokuwiki.org/), one of the first PHP projects to implement a *web bug* for an actually useful purpose (search indexing).

Comment: As a note, the ob_start are probably used to avoid printing warnings. Quite frankly, I don't rememeber.

Comment: while i GREATLY appreciate what you wrote out here, it isn't working still. I enabled buffering again also.

Comment: I've used this code with success a bunch of times. I'm sorry it does not work for you. I also suggest you don't output anything from your script (but spit a 500 header if things go wrong).

Comment: Thanks tacone.  I do appreciate the script.  Its really well thought out.  I really think its something my hosting company is blocking though.  Not sure but I had this working and then all of a sudden it wasnt.

Answer (score 1):

So this issue is because ""OutputBufferSize 0" needs to be set in the FastCGI configuration, otherwise mod_fcgid will do it's own output buffering in addition to PHPs."  This is something I didnt have control over on my hosting server.  Hope this helps someone!!